# Imagens estilo postagens caroussel com botão de próximo e anterior

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Gente, estou precisando desenvolver uma exibição de postagens, mas em estilo caroussel, um ao lado do outro, e com o botão de próximo e anterior passando ou voltando as postagens.. Alguém poderia ajudar? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Como assim postagem ? o
 não serve? [Caroussel do Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) não serve?

Comment: @WilliamCézar eu preciso de um como esse do topo "http://www.filmesonlinegratis.com/" (últimos lançamentos) com botão de próximo e anterior..